# Draw images and text in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox in WindowsForms and I draw items manually. Each item is composed from picture and text (Cell.Image and Cell.Title), so item is 34 px height.

My problem is that when I drop down ComboBox, only 1 item is visible. MaxDropDownItems = 4 so ComboBox would draw 4 items. I know that I have set DropDownHeight = 34, but I want to display empty rectangle when there is no item in ComboBox like on the following picture.

ComboBox with no item - OK:
[image: ComboBox with no item - OK]

ComboBox with only 1 visible item - Bad:
[image: ComboBox with only 1 visible item - Bad]

My class derived from ComboBox:

```
public class ComboBoxCells : ComboBox
{
    private List<Cell> _cells;

    public List<Cell> Cells
    {
        get { return this._cells; }
        set
        {
            this._cells = value;
            this.BeginUpdate();
            this.Items.Clear();

            if (value != null)
                this.Items.AddRange(value.ToArray());

            this.EndUpdate();
        }
    }

    public ComboBoxCells()
    {
        this.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        this.DropDownHeight = 34;
        this.DropDownWidth = 200;
        this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.MaxDropDownItems = 4;

        this.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ComboBoxCells_DrawItem);
        this.MeasureItem += new MeasureItemEventHandler(ComboBoxCells_MeasureItem);
    }

    private void ComboBoxCells_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Draw item inside comboBox
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit) != DrawItemState.ComboBoxEdit && e.Index > -1)
        {
            Cell item = this.Items[e.Index] as Cell;

            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 6, e.Bounds.Top + 6, 22, 22));

            e.Graphics.DrawImage(item.Image, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Left + 7, e.Bounds.Top + 7, 20, 20));

            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Title, e.Font,
                    new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds.Left + 34, e.Bounds.Top + 10);
        }
        // Draw visible text
        else if (e.Index > -1)
        {
            Cell item = this.Items[e.Index] as Cell;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(item.Title, e.Font,
                    new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor), e.Bounds.Left, e.Bounds.Top);
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }

    private void ComboBoxCells_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ItemHeight = 34;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

DropDownHeight is the number you want to set higher.  It is the maximum number of pixels for the drop down box.  The system will automatically make it the largest multiple of your item height.

```
this.DropDownHeight = 200;
```

Comment: I set this.DropDownHeight = 170 because 5 * 34 = 170. But when I scroll down the combobox, there is 34px height white space: [link](http://i.imgur.com/EFEkR.png) Is there any solution to remove this white space? In normal ComboBox there is no white space like in this.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `IntegralHeight` to true it will resize the drop down list so it doesn't show partial items. It should get rid of the white space.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ComboBoxCells() constructor`, add default cell item that can draw white rectangle of 34 px height.

In `List<Cell> Cells Set property`, remove that item and add new items specified by `value.ToArray()`. This makes sure that default item is removed whenever list of items are specified, otherwise draw default item.

In your `ComboBoxCells_DrawItem() event`, handle this change with `e.Index = 0` condition and draw the rectangle.

Hope this approach works for you.